# Links not using <style> tag or, css not supported?

Tags: windows, html, css, links

I'm using links as a text based browser on windows. It's supposed too render in the middle bottom of links, but it's not. It's ignoring the CSS entirely it'd seem.

Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <style>
 html,body {
   height:100%;  /* new */
 }

ul#navigation {
    height: 70px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 0;    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Cham-WebFont', Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;   /* new */
    bottom: 0;  /* new */
    width: 100%;  /* new */
}

ul#navigation li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: .75em;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#navigation li.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="MainContainer">
        </div>  
    <div id="MenuContainer">
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li>Text</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Is this the default behavior of links? Or did I overlook something?

**EDIT**

If helpful: Image of output[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a source, links **IGNORES** css. (Source being a links developer)

Evidence (suggesting such);

From http://links.twibright.com/features.php:

> HTML 4.0 support (without CSS)